# List Value getting deleted

Tags: java, android, list, listview

I have created a list inside a class which extends activity,

```
    public static     List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

And i'm adding value for this in another class using  the line

`ListHistory.myList.add(0, temp);`

where temp is a string.
I can see the list of values in my app , but in some situations like force close or after switch off/on of mobile the list is getting null. So anybody know why this is happening ?

Comment: you need to add try / exception

Answer (score 0):

because static block will be nullified on every memory recycle .

so don't make it static . there is no need for it in any case .

`putEstra()` or `persistant storage` .

Comment: he try to call myList in another class so he has to define as static

Comment: Yup, thats why i made it static. But if i remove it i need to create a object which is not be a universal and i think its value gets off after exiting app... I need to store value after the user comes back to app.. This is im getting by using static but as u said its getting nullified. I think i cant store list in shared preferences too.

Comment: make list global by declaring it into Application class

Answer (score 0):

Static variables are to be avoided at all costs because they lead to memory leaks(a static variable will be garbage collected once your application is CLOSED). Using them is only justified for declaring constants and nothing else. You can either instantiated the ListHistory class from where you want to use this list and create a getter for the list, or you can use `SharedPreferences` to save this history.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html